# FormatConditions and Interior Color

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2003, vba

I have an old macro that was working fine on Excel 2003 but creates issues with Excel 2010. The part that causes problems is:

```
If Not IsNull(someRange.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.Color) Then
    locVisibleColor = someRange.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.Color
End if
```

where `parActiveCondition` is the active conditional formatting number on `someRange`.

When the background is selected as "No Color", `someRange.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.Color` returns

- `Null` in Excel 2003
- 0 in Excel 2010

The problem is that a black background also returns 0. So in Excel 2010 it seems no longer possible to make the difference between a black background and no background color.

Does anybody know a workaround?

ps: I could obviously select a white background instead of "No Color" but I'd rather not change all the spreadsheets and conditional formatting rules.

Comment: I think `TintAndShade` is `Null` for `No Color` but 0 for black. So this could distinguish between the 2 as a secondary test

Comment: @brettdj That seems to do the trick - Feel free to post as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Boolean secondary check such as

```
IsNull(someRange.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.ColorIndex) 'or
IsNull(someRange.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.TintAndShade)
```

when

```
.FormatConditions(parActiveCondition).Interior.Color = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim Color
Dim R As Integer
Dim G As Integer
Dim B As Integer

Color = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Interior.Color


R = Color Mod 256
G = (Color \ 256) Mod 256
B = (Color \ 256 \ 256) Mod 256

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)

End Sub
```

Black returns (0,0,0)
It appears however that "no color" returns (255,255,255) (=white)

Comment: Does it still work with some conditional formatting on (say: red if <0 with no colour background)? And this is not the function that I'm calling.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand your question. But it seems that you found the answer to your question. Fun question, something you don't think about every day.

Comment: @Assylias You are right, it doesn't work with conditional formatting. I should have checked that. Just as a sidenote: I usually write a function to perform formatting conditions with a select case and have the function return a "state" (Integer, boolean, depending). This way the state can be checked upon a direct number rather than a color.

Comment: Here is my use case: I read some cells, determine which conditional formatting rule is active, if any, then determine what the format of the cell is (based on the active rule) then use that to produce external HTML reports that reproduce the visible formatting.

Comment: In that case, my code is unfortunately useless. I just did the test, and it doesn't return the color of the conditional format applied at a certain point in time. It just returns "White". I'll leave my reply as info.